# Docker volume size limit on BlueMix

Tags: docker, ibm-cloud, docker-volume

Docker containers let us conveniently mount volumes for persistent data. I've researched this, and if I understand correctly, the volume's space allocation is bound by the container host's drive space.

My question is - how does this translate to a cloud system like Bluemix? With a container(on **Bluemix**), you can set the drive limit to, say,  32GB, etc, and know you can run the image with 32GB available TO the container. Are any created volumes also capped and folled into that 32GB limit?

I'm not able to find any documentation on this. The closest I found was creating "Data Containers", where the volume limit is the size of the data container. But if I just create a volume and mount it to a container, what rules govern the size limit of that particular volume?

running inspect

```
{
    "hostPath": "/vol/af2f348b-cad6-4b86-ac0c-b1bc072ca241/PGDATA",
    "spaceGuid": "af2f348b-cad6-4b86-ac0c-b1bc072ca241",
    "volName": "PGDATA"
}
```

This question seems specific to Bluemix, but not necessarily, since it might shed light on practices other "container as a service" providers might use.

Answer (score 2):

On Bluemix you could use external docker volumes for data persistence: if a storage is inside a container its persistence will be limited to when the container is running.

You could create a volume using the cf CLI

```
cf ic volume create volume_name
```

and check for it through

```
cf ic volume list
```

Then you could mount it on the container on Bluemix through the cf ic command with **-v** option, or through the dockerfile when building on Bluemix

For a reference
https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_single_ov.html

Edit Jan 18th

There is a relationship between memory and storage size for containers on Bluemix, it is shown by the dashboard options (according to the account/org type)

- Pico: 64 MB Memory, 4GB Storage
- Nano: 128 MB Memory, 8GB Storage
- Micro: 256 MB Memory, 16GB Storage (default)
- Tiny: 512 MB Memory, 32GB Storage
- Small: 1GB Memory, 64GB Storage
- Medium: 2 GB Memory, 128GB Storage
- Large: 4 GB Memory, 256GB Storage
- X-Large: 8 GB Memory, 512GB Storage
- XX-Large: 16 GB Memory, 1TB Storage

Comment: I have a paying account, however, you have to choose a "tier" when you run a new container in Bluemix. For example, the "Micro" tier has 256MB ram/16GB container space. My question is about the volume size when you take into account the allocated space of the plan the container lives in. I believe the real answer is it's limited to that 16GB, but I was curious since the docs do not state this anywhere directly for mounted volumes.